# Getting Jaccard similarity between two columns in one dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to compute Jaccard similarity of two columns and I don't think there's a function like that in PySpark. I'm not sure what is the best way to compute that.

For example, say that we have 1 dataframe that looks like this:

```
| str1 | str2 |
===============
|  hi  |   h  |
|  me  |   p  |
```

These columns are all Stringtype and the end result should look like this:

```
| str1 | str2 | jaccard |
=========================
|  hi  |   h  |    0.5  |
|  me  |   p  |    0    |
```

I wrote a udf like this but it's not working. I am still quite new to Spark so it must be broken. I'm open to any solutions as long as it computes accurately Jaccard sim of 2 columns in 1 dataframe.

```py
jaccard = udf(lambda x, y: len(set(x).intersection(y))/len(set(x).union(y)))
candidates = candidates.withColumn("jaccard", jaccard(col("str1"), col("str2")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I debugged my own question. The following code returned Jaccard similarity.

```
jac = f.udf(lambda x, y: float(len(set(x).intersection(y)))/float(len(set(x).union(y))))
myDF = myDF.withColumn("jaccard", jac(myDF["str1"], myDF["str2"]))
```